# Running time in a java application

Tags: java

So if you were to use something like this to get the time off the computer that the program would be running off of, what would be the best way to keep a running clock? I know that you would be able to infinitely loop the clock and have it keep refreshing every 1 millisecond or so, but what would be a better way to do it?

```
String timeStamp = new
SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
```

Comment: call [`System.currentTimeMillis()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis--) at the start and end, calculate the delta. If `System.currentTimeMills()` is too coarse-grained, you can use [`System.nanoTime()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime--).

Comment: Downvoted because [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

new Date() is somewhat faster than Calendar.getInstance().getTime()

Anyways, there is no need to keep running time I guess, whenever you need a timestamp you can update your timestamp with `timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());`.

Can you clarify your use-case for running time? If you could, it would be easier to find the best solution for your problem. If you need a process to trigger at the specific time, using java.util.Timer is also an option.

Comment: I was thinking of making a calendar program that lets you add reminders on certain days and stuff of that nature. So I wanted to add a running clock in the program displaying Date/Time

Comment: I suppose you are making a desktop app. You will need to have a new thread which will keep updating your timestamp label in aforementioned way while app is running. ```while (true){label.setText(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date()));}``` should be the simplest solution. It is up to you to determine how you want to initialize the new thread, there are multiple ways to do so.

Comment: Thank you, that's pretty close to what I was thinking of doing originally using calendar and then using .get to get yyyy/mm/dd/hh/mm/ss

Comment: Glad I could help. :)

Answer (score 0):

Why not using java.util.Timer instead of a loop

Comment: So like get the time off the system initially and then use timer to increment the time?

Comment: Yes, that's the way to go. With a delay of 1s.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a class like this:

```
public class Timei {

static void t(Runnable block) {
    Instant start = Instant.now();
    try {
        block.run();
    } finally {
        Instant end = Instant.now();
        Duration d = Duration.between(start, end);
        System.out.println("duration (seconds): " + d.getSeconds() + "," + d.getNano());
    }
}
}
```

... and call the static method t like this:

```
Timei.t(() -> {
        //Some code to measure
    });
```

e.g. if you want to calculate the duration of this code:

```
    System.out.println(
        IntStream.range(0, 1_000_000)
                .filter(m -> m % 7 == 0)
                .boxed()
                .collect(toList()));
```

just "wrap it" like this:

```
Timei.t(() -> {
System.out.println(
        IntStream.range(0, 1_000_000)
                .filter(m -> m % 7 == 0)
                .boxed()
                .collect(toList()));
 });
```